# select value from xml field in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is My Xml File,Tt is is a field of a Table, How I can Select from it?The Result Format is: pIdentityCode,ApplyPercent,CI_Ability,CI_Base,CI_CancelType,CI_Years
I can't write a select Query for it.If anybody Know about that Please tell me about that.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">http://SErvice.com/PublishEngineerToOthers/srvEngineerToOthers.svc</To>
    <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IsrvEngineerToOthers/SaveRef_Info</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SaveRef_Info xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <pCode>gdyFlNN847tyCqSLnUkm5w==</pCode>
      <pNidWorkItem>600348</pNidWorkItem>
      <pIdentityCode>1261919491</pIdentityCode>
      <pRefInfo xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataAccess.Engineers" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ApplyPercent>100</a:ApplyPercent>
        <a:CI_Ability>2</a:CI_Ability>
        <a:CI_Base>2</a:CI_Base>
        <a:CI_CancelType>0</a:CI_CancelType>
        <a:CI_Years>1396</a:CI_Years>
        <a:CancelDate i:nil="true" />
        <a:CommitmentDate i:nil="true" />
        <a:ConfirmCoordinatorDate i:nil="true" />
        <a:ConfirmCoordinatorNisUser i:nil="true" />
        <a:ConfirmCoordinatorTime i:nil="true" />
        <a:ConfirmCoordinatorUserName i:nil="true" />
        <a:ConfirmDate>1396/08/21</a:ConfirmDate>
<a:CreditValue i:nil="true" />
    <a:DateOfRefrence>1396/08/21</a:DateOfRefrence>
    <a:EumCoordinatorStatus i:nil="true" />
    <a:IdentityCode i:nil="true" />
    <a:IsBuildingExecRepCompleteAndConfirm i:nil="true" />
    <a:IsCanceled>false</a:IsCanceled>
    <a:IsCommitment>false</a:IsCommitment>
    <a:IsConfirm>false</a:IsConfirm>
    <a:IsCoordinator>false</a:IsCoordinator>
    <a:IsDynamic i:nil="true" />
    <a:IsEngExecuter>false</a:IsEngExecuter>
    <a:IsEngOwner>false</a:IsEngOwner>
    <a:IsExecuterQta i:nil="true" />
    <a:IsFree>false</a:IsFree>
    <a:IsFriend>false</a:IsFriend>
    <a:IsRelease>false</a:IsRelease>
    <a:IsSwitchEngineer>false</a:IsSwitchEngineer>
    <a:NIdEng i:nil="true" />
    <a:NIdFil>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:NIdFil>
    <a:NIdMem i:nil="true" />
    <a:NIdOff i:nil="true" />
    <a:NIdRef>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:NIdRef>
    <a:NIdRef_tmp>0</a:NIdRef_tmp>
    <a:NidTask i:nil="true" />
    <a:RefComments />
    <a:ReferDate>1396/08/21</a:ReferDate>
    <a:ReferNidUser i:nil="true" />
    <a:RevokeCoordinatorUserName i:nil="true" />
    <a:SwitchEngineerDate i:nil="true" />
    <a:SysCI_ReferType>0</a:SysCI_ReferType>
  </pRefInfo>
</SaveRef_Info>
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger I Edited,Can You See Again?

Comment: it's not a complete / proper XML

Comment: @Raska It is a part of It, What do you need? Please Tell Me?

Comment: it's better to give XML with proper ending tags for testing..anyway, I have posted an answer.

Comment: @Raska I Edited That,Please see again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as s, 'http://tempuri.org/' as ns)
SELECT t.saveref.value('*:pIdentityCode[1]','varchar(max)') AS pIdentityCode,
t.saveref.value('(*:pRefInfo/*:ApplyPercent)[1]','int') AS ApplyPercent,
t.saveref.value('(*:pRefInfo/*:CI_Ability)[1]','int') AS CI_Ability
FROM @X.nodes('/s:Envelope/s:Body/ns:SaveRef_Info') as  t(saveref)
```

Comment: It dosn't work for me

Comment: Omid, edited the answer. This gives values for your xml.